# add style to npm ShowMore component for preview dispay

Tags: npm, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying justify a text in a ShowMore component. But my current code justify only when the text is totally dispay - not in the "showLess" case.

```
<p style={{ marginTop: '0.7em', textAlign: 'justify' }}>
    <ShowMore
        lines={4}
        more="plus"
        less="moins"
        anchorClass=""
    >
       {this.content}
    </ShowMore>
</p>
```

How to apply the style on the showless mode too ?

Here the complete class :

```
class News extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.event = { title: 'some title for this event' };
    this.content = 'Nec minus feminae quoque calamitatum participes fuere similium. nam ex hoc quoque sexu peremptae sunt originis altae conplures, adulteriorum flagitiis obnoxiae vel stuprorum. inter quas notiores fuere Claritas et Flaviana, quarum altera cum duceretur ad mortem, indumento, quo vestita erat, abrepto.';
}

render() {
    return (
        <Segment>
            <p>{this.event.title}</p>
            <p style={{ marginTop: '0.7em', textAlign: 'justify' }}>
                <ShowMore
                    lines={3}
                    more="plus"
                    less="moins"
                    anchorClass=""
                >
                    {this.content}
                </ShowMore>
            </p>
        </Segment>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Izaya

Comment: I just installed react-show-more and tried making a basic component. Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce your problem. Probably something in the `less` class is overriding the styles in the wrapper element. If you still need help, could you please post enough code that we can recreate your problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying helping me. I updated the code. Hoping it will help you :)

Comment: Still unable to reproduce your problem I'm afraid. For me, the text is justified in both modes.